# Phone Regex (555) 555-5555 with out using brackets {}

Tags: regex

I need to match phone numbers with this format

(555) 555-5555

I have found around this

```
\(?\b[0-9]{3}\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}\b
```

I know that is the correct way but in the platform that I am using there is a bug that removes the {} brackets out of the regex code. I have already reported the bug but it might take a while for them to fix it and release the update so I am wondering if there is another way to accomplish the same with out using brackets.

Comment: Are you sure it's a bug and not your implementation? What platform are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[0-9]{3}` is the same thing as `[0-9][0-9][0-9]` or `\d\d\d`

In full that would look like this:

```
\(?\b[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9][0-9][0-9][-. ]?[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\b
```

or

```
\(?\b\d\d\d\)?[-. ]?\d\d\d[-. ]?\d\d\d\d\b
```

Comment: You were quicker! :-) If the platform supports it then the \d\d\d is the cleanest. Unfortunately \d isn't available in all regex engines.

Comment: I suppose I'm not familiar with every platform, but I imagine if `\b` is available, `\d` probably is as well. Either way I guess its good there is another option.

Answer (score 0):

just use `\d` for each characcter you need to match

`[0-9]{3}` is `\d\d\d`

`[0-9]{4}` is `\d\d\d\d`

Answer (score 0):

Well, sure. Instead of saying "apply pattern {n} times", write "patternpatternpattern..." n times:

```
\(?\b[0-9][0-9]0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9][0-9][0-9][-. ]?[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the brackets with the given number of iterations of the sequence before the bracket.

```
\(?\b[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)?[-. ]?[0-9][0-9][0-9][-. ]?[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\b
```